# Exception with JdbcTemplate update using PreparedStatement to insert data

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using jdbcTemplate's prepared statement to write some data to a table. Currently, I am facing the following exception and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
private void insertdata(String time, String data, Datasource datasource){
  String sql = "insert into table1 (columns1, columns2) values (:time, :data)";
  jdbcTemplate jdbctemplate = new jdbcTemplate(datasource);
  Object[] params = {time, data};
  int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
   try{
        jdbctemplate.update(sql, params, types);
   }catch(Exception e){
        //some error handling 
   }
  }
```

I am getting the following exception in logs.

```
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into table1 (columns1, columns2) values (:time, :data)]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

I don't know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: WHy are you not using `SqlMapParamSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're still using JDBC under the hood - so recode your statement to

```
String sql = "insert into table1 (columns1, columns2) values (?,?)";
```

And you'll be fine **or**

Use [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) as your template.

Answer (score 0):

JdbcTemplate does not support named parameters like (:Name, :ID) use (?,?) placeholders instead or use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate or SimpleJdbcDaoSupport to fix the error